# Adding tail behaviour where enter adds blank lines to less

Tags: linux, tail, less

I love `less`, which I can use to follow logs with the `+F` flag (or the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> hotkey), search forwards and backwards, and generally move freely through the document.

But there is one thing missing in `less`: usually I am at the end of the file, and I want to see new things happening. In `tail -f` I would just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> several times, and new log lines would just appear clearly separated from old lines.

Is it possible to add this to `less`? How?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, though sometimes I will do echo -e '\n\n\n\n\n' >> /dev/pts/0 for example, it isn't as clean but atleast lets me have a point of reference where I left off when i look away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really `tail`'s behavior -- it's the terminal. Tail is just sending a stream of output to stdout, which goes to your terminal, and you're inserting blank lines in the middle of that output by hitting enter. Tail itself isn't actually accepting input from you at all. You can type whatever else you want and that will show up too.

`less`, however, is a console app, and it takes input and processes it. It's managing the console using terminal control sequences, which is how you can scroll around. Letting you insert arbitrary characters into the stream would mess up the display, and anyway less uses your input to control the program.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have a way to mark the current position visually. That's not a terrible feature request, though, and less *does* still get new features from time to time.

Comment: Do you have a link at hand to request this feature to the less mantainers?

Comment: @gonvaled http://www.gnu.org/software/less/

Answer (score 4):

I found your question while seeking the same answer for myself.

Disappointed by the accepted answer, I came up with a workaround. It's less than ideal, but it allows me to mark my position in the log I'm following with `less`, which is the whole point.

I created a small executable script (I called it `marklog`) with the following contents, and put it in my path:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo >> $1
echo >> $1
echo >> $1
echo `date` ---------------------------------------------------------------------- >> $1
echo >> $1
echo >> $1
```

Of course, this only works if you have write access to the log file--which could be a deal-breaker in many situations. I've also created this version which I use to write to  log files I don't own (but to which I have sudo access):

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo sh -c "echo >> $1"
sudo sh -c "echo >> $1"
sudo sh -c "echo >> $1"
sudo sh -c "echo `date` ------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> $1"
sudo sh -c "echo >> $1"
sudo sh -c "echo >> $1"
```

These scripts provide just the sort of visual break I was looking for. There are at least 3 ways you can use them:

1. At the point where you would normally press enter a few times when using `tail -f`,  instead run `marklog` from another terminal (providing the path to the log file as an argument).
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend `less` so you can run the script in the same terminal window, but when you re-foreground `less` (using `fg`, of course), it will no longer be in 'follow' mode, so you'll need to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> again...
3. Lastly--and this might be the most convenient way, because you don't need to type the path to the log file: Run `marklog` directly from `less` by typing `!marklog %`. `Less` will substitute the current filename for `%`. However, `less` won't respond to the ! while it is in 'follow' mode, so you'll have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> first to exit follow mode, run `!marklog %`, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> again.

With method 3, you also get the added bonus of of Less's command history: Just hit the `!` and then use the up-arrow to select the most recent command (for me, it's always `marklog`).

Hope this helps someone as much as has already helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> at the end of file and less will start to work as `tail -f`.

Comment: No, it won't. It will follow new lines, but it will not work as `tail -f`. Specifically it will not accept enter as newlines, which is the  *only* point of my question. Besides, I already mentioned `Shift+F` in the question (with a small error, I must say)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. I've used `m` and `'` to mark places of interest and then goto them again but this doesn't give you the separation that you ask for. Perhaps something like multitail will do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Lambart brings me to my favorite solution. Thx to Lambart!

Just interput the follow mode <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and enter `!printf "\n\n---$(date)---\n\n" >> %`. After that you have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> one more time and hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to start again following the file.